# PHP allocating less than maximum fails

Tags: php, memory, memory-limit

This one is easy to ask - hopefully quite as easy to answer:

Can anyone explain how this is in any way possible?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error notices says that PHP tried to use 183200 bytes **additional** memory to the already used memory (something between 1341994528 and 1342177727 bytes) and this breaks the maximum of the allowed 1342177728 bytes.

You have to (edit your php.ini and) [extend the memory limit of PHP](http://www.teknobites.com/how-to-edit-phpini-file-to-increase-memory-limit/).

Comment: what a shame! i was not aware this message speaks about "additional" allocated memory. and i should have mentioned in my question, that i know how to allocate more memory. i was just curious about how this (to me) seemingly "illogical error" could come up. anyway, issue solved. thank you.

Comment: Yes, the notice is misunderstandable. Search near this line in the script where the error occurred and try to unset not anymore used variables. For example some large data sets.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Unfortunately there is no way to further optimize this code. Its for generating waveforms in high detail. But its okay - i only run this once for every file and of course am caching the result.

Answer (score 1):

The message means php is trying to allocate an *extra* 183200 bytes on top of what it already had, so this last "drop" makes it go over the limit.

A solution could be to [increase the memory limit](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=php+increase+memory+limit&qscrl=1), but it's better if you refactor your code so that it doesn't take so much memory (if possible).

Answer (score 0):

Because at the point that the memory request was made, less than 183200 bytes were still unused in that maximum-sized block of 134217728.

It's like asking for a full glass of milk from a jug, but only a couple drops are left.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [memory limit in php.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit). Your php application is allocating memory (and freeing it if it's not needed anymore) and php engine limits maximal amount of memory that can be used at the time by one script.